# How to set Ruby's load path externally

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have a custom Ruby library directory that I'd like to have automatically added to Ruby's load path whenever Ruby is executed.  I know I can use the `-I` option to Ruby, but is there something like an environment variable that I can set that will globally determine Ruby's load path.

I want to install Ruby Gems on a Linux box where I don't have root privileges, so I need to have a Ruby load path in a non-standard location.  I installed RubyGems per "[Installing RubyGems in a User Directory](http://rubygems.org/read/chapter/3#page83)", but the `gem` command isn't picking up the non-standard load path.

Maybe I'm missing something obvious here and making things harder for myself?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

See the "[Ruby and Its World](http://phrogz.net/ProgrammingRuby/rubyworld.html)" chapter from The Pickaxe Book, specifically the section on environment variables. Excerpt:

```
RUBYLIB 
  Additional search path for Ruby programs ($SAFE must be 0).
DLN_LIBRARY_PATH
  Search path for dynamically loaded modules.
RUBYLIB_PREFIX
  (Windows only) Mangle the RUBYLIB search path by adding this
  prefix to each component.
```

Comment: RUBYLIB did the trick.  I'm not sure why an hour of googling was not able to dig up this information.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that you've placed the installed `bin` directory in your `$PATH` for the `gem`
command to work.  It should modify the `RUBYLIB` itself, but if not, try [Martin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901085/setting-ruby-load-path-externally/901109#901109) to fix that.

Then, you can have your gem home (where the gems that rubygems installs are stored) be local.

Just use `$GEM_HOME` (or set things up in your `~/.gemrc`) and check that everything took with `gem environment`.

```
% mkdir ~/.gems
% export GEM_HOME=~/.gems
% gem help environment

Usage: gem environment [arg] [options]

  Common Options:
    -h, --help                       Get help on this command
    -V, --[no-]verbose               Set the verbose level of output
    -q, --quiet                      Silence commands
        --config-file FILE           Use this config file instead of default
        --backtrace                  Show stack backtrace on errors
        --debug                      Turn on Ruby debugging


  Arguments:
    packageversion  display the package version
    gemdir          display the path where gems are installed
    gempath         display path used to search for gems
    version         display the gem format version
    remotesources   display the remote gem servers
           display everything

  Summary:
    Display information about the RubyGems environment

  Description:
    The RubyGems environment can be controlled through command line arguments,
    gemrc files, environment variables and built-in defaults.

    Command line argument defaults and some RubyGems defaults can be set in
    ~/.gemrc file for individual users and a /etc/gemrc for all users.  A gemrc
    is a YAML file with the following YAML keys:

      :sources: A YAML array of remote gem repositories to install gems from
      :verbose: Verbosity of the gem command.  false, true, and :really are the
                levels
      :update_sources: Enable/disable automatic updating of repository metadata
      :backtrace: Print backtrace when RubyGems encounters an error
      :bulk_threshold: Switch to a bulk update when this many sources are out of
                       date (legacy setting)
      :gempath: The paths in which to look for gems
      gem_command: A string containing arguments for the specified gem command

    Example:

      :verbose: false
      install: --no-wrappers
      update: --no-wrappers

    RubyGems' default local repository can be overriden with the GEM_PATH and
    GEM_HOME environment variables.  GEM_HOME sets the default repository to
    install into.  GEM_PATH allows multiple local repositories to be searched
    for
    gems.

    If you are behind a proxy server, RubyGems uses the HTTP_PROXY,
    HTTP_PROXY_USER and HTTP_PROXY_PASS environment variables to discover the
    proxy server.

    If you are packaging RubyGems all of RubyGems' defaults are in
    lib/rubygems/defaults.rb.  You may override these in
    lib/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb
```

Answer (score 1):

Make life easy and install [RVM](http://rvm.io/). It will install whatever version of Ruby you want and let you switch between them and it doesn't require root access. It has many other killer features you will become addicted to after using it for a while.

Comment: How to add a library at a custom location with RVM?

Comment: I don't think this answers the OP question.

Comment: How did this answer get 4 upvotes should be  a separate SO question

Comment: Either RVM or rbenv will do this, but either way this answer sidesteps the OPs question so it's not really germane.

Answer (score 1):

I used [@MartinCarpenter's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/901109/242933) to run a specific/particular/single test method with [minitest](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest). Where I normally add the `test` directory to the `$LOAD_PATH` with [Rake::TestTask](http://rake.rubyforge.org/classes/Rake/TestTask.html), e.g., `t.libs << 'test'`, I was able to do it with the command line, like so:

```
RUBYLIB=test ruby test/user_test.rb --name test_create
```

I added `test` to `$LOAD_PATH` because `user_test.rb` calls `require 'test_helper'` to load `lib/test_helper.rb`.