# How to add something to Ruby's load path

Tags: ruby, macos, unix

I want to add a folder "`~/Projects/Scripts`" to use `require *script*` where `*script*` is a Ruby file in this directory.

How does the `require` method work? Does it load from a environment variable and if so what?

Answer (score 1):

See "[How to set Ruby's load path externally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901085/setting-ruby-load-path-externally)".

The answer is that you set the `RUBYLIB` environment variable to add items to the list of paths that Ruby searches.

Answer (score 1):

`$LOAD_PATH` or `$:` or `$-I` is array of string holding the directories to be searched when load the files with the `load` or `require` methods. You can append new directories as you did for normal array.

```
 >> $:
 => ["deleted_for_simplicity","/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/i386-linux", "."]

 >> $: << "/opt/project"
 => ["deleted_for_simplicity","/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/i386-linux", ".", "/opt/project"]
```