# Ruby require load error

Tags: ruby, rubygems, require

I'm trying to require two gems: json and rinku.

I'm working on a hosted Linux box and do not have root/sudo access and have ended up with the gems being installed in my home directory:

```
-jailshell-3.2$ gem which json
/home/cygnetrc/ruby/gems/gems/json-1.7.3/lib/json.rb
-jailshell-3.2$ gem which rinku
/home/cygnetrc/ruby/gems/gems/rinku-1.5.1/lib/rinku.rb
```

The Ruby version is:

```
-jailshell-3.2$ ruby --version
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [x86_64-linux]
```

The RubyGems environment is:

```
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.11
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/cygnetrc/ruby/gems
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/cygnetrc/ruby/gems/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/cygnetrc/ruby/gems
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gempath" => []
     - "gem" => "--remote --gen-rdoc --run-tests"
     - "gemhome" => "/home/cygnetrc/ruby/gems"
     - "rdoc" => "--inline-source --line-numbers"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/


-jailshell-3.2$ ruby -e 'puts $:'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux
.
```

I tried to include the gems using:

```
-jailshell-3.2$ head gettweets.rb 
#!/usr/bin/ruby 

require 'rubygems'
require 'json'
require 'net/https'
require 'uri'
require 'rinku'
```

But end up with:

```
-jailshell-3.2$ ./gettweets.rb 
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- json (LoadError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from ./gettweets.rb:7
```

I looked around extensively and found lots of information about various different path variables like RUBYOPTS, but nothing seems to be working for me.

To complicate matters further, I am going to be calling the script from a cron job so whatever solution I use it can't be dependent on altering anything in my home directory like my .profile.

I'm pulling my hair out - can anyone help?

---

UPDATE:

Thanks for your feedback! Following some of your advice I read up on `GEM_PATH` which works if I set and export it as a shell environment variable. However, since I want to run the script from cron I need to be able to set it from within the script itself. I've tried to do this but it doesn't seem to be working. Any further thoughts?

```
-jailshell-3.2$ ruby -I ~/ruby/gems ./gettweets.rb 
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- json (LoadError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from ./gettweets.rb:4
-jailshell-3.2$ head -20 ./gettweets.rb 
#!/usr/bin/ruby 

require 'rubygems'
require 'json'
require 'net/https'
require 'uri'
require 'rinku'
require 'optparse'

OptionParser.new do |o|
  o.on('-d', "Turn on debugging messages") { |b| $debug = b }
  o.on('-h', "Print this help screen") { puts o; exit }
  o.parse!
end

puts "[*] Starting..." if $debug

# Setenv to catch json gem
ENV['GEM_PATH'] = '~/ruby/gems'
puts "ENV " + ENV['GEM_PATH'] if $debug
-jailshell-3.2$ export GEM_PATH=~/ruby/gems
-jailshell-3.2$ ruby ./gettweets.rb  -d
[*] Starting...
ENV ~/ruby/gems
[*] Filepath = /home/cygnetrc/www/drupal/tweets.html
The queens of the women's single sculls - a look back at the Olympic history: http://t.co/d0YmNr40 #rowing #wr #London2012 #Olympics<br />
<em>Fri Jun 08 16:05:38</em><br />
1 week until #WRCMunich! NZL's Storm Uru will be racing the LM2x with @petertaylorNZ. Here, Uru talks about teamwork: http://t.co/NvjRgtwW<br />
<em>Fri Jun 08 14:38:02</em><br />
The 2012 @Paralympic Games Qualification Process is complete: http://t.co/D6DRG0bO #rowing #adaptive #Paralympic #London2012 #wr<br />
<em>Fri Jun 08 13:23:14</em><br />
true
[*] Finished
-jailshell-3.2$
```

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901085/setting-ruby-load-path-externally

Comment: You have `gempath` defined in your `.gemrc`? Try removing that and see if it helps.

Comment: do yourself a favour and use rvm.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar issue running Ruby through Apache mod_cgi. The environment variables weren't getting set, but the CGI scripts are run as the user not Apache. This was my workaround.

```
#!/bin/bash
source "/home/username/.bashrc"
rubyscript.cgi
```

But, I would like a real way to add to the gems path in the Ruby script itself to avoid such workarounds and found this:

```
ENV["HOME"] = "/home/user"
ENV["GEM_HOME"] = ENV["HOME"] + "/ruby/gems"
ENV["GEM_PATH"] = ENV["GEM_HOME"] + ":/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8"
ENV["GEM_CACHE"] = "GEM_HOME/cache"
ENV["PATH"] = ENV["PATH"] + ":" + ENV["HOME"] + "/ruby/gems/bin"
```

This can be put in the head of the Ruby script or put in a file and "required" at the beginning, i.e. environment.rb:

```
ENV["HOME"] = "/home/user"
ENV["GEM_HOME"] = ENV["HOME"] + "/ruby/gems"
ENV["GEM_PATH"] = ENV["GEM_HOME"] + ":/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8"
ENV["GEM_CACHE"] = "GEM_HOME/cache"
ENV["PATH"] = ENV["PATH"] + ":" + ENV["HOME"] + "/ruby/gems/bin"
```

ruby.cgi:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require "environment"
require "rubygems"
require "json"
puts "Content-type: text/json"
puts ""
puts "{'bacon':['yum','tasty']}"
```